# Unable to properly Transform nested array with JOLT

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I'm trying to convert json nested array's element and unable to get expected result, either I properly get name element or schemaExtensions element but can't get both together.

Here is my input:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "content": {
        "name": {
          "content": "User"
        },
        "schemaExtensions": {
          "content": [
            {
              "content": {
                "schema": {
                  "content": "User"
                },
                "required": {
                  "content": true
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And the JOlt spec definition:

```
  [
    {
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
        "rows": {
          "*": {
            "content": {
              "name": {
                "content": "[&3].name"
              },
              "schemaExtensions": {
                "content": {
                  "*": {
                    "content": {
                      "schema": {
                        "content": "schemaExtensions.[&7].schema"
                      },
                      "required": {
                        "content": "schemaExtensions.[&7].required"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
]
```

The expected result:

```
[ {
  "name" : "User",
  "schemaExtensions": [ {
       "schema":"User",
       "required":true
    }]
}]
```

Here is the result I got when having both in my spec

```
[ {
  "name" : "User"
} ]
```

And if I remove name from my spec, then I get my schemaExtensions properly:

```
{
  "schemaExtensions" : [ {
    "schema" : "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User",
    "required" : true
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "rows": {
            "*": {
              "content": {
                "name": {
                  "content": "[].name"
                },
                "schemaExtensions": {
                  "content": {
                    "*": {
                      "content": {
                        "schema": {
                          "content": "[&7].schemaExtensions[&7].schema"
                        },
                        "required": {
                          "content": "[&7].schemaExtensions[&7].required"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Thks, only thing I change, I kept [&3].name and everything work perfectly as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can start with three level nesting to roam before writing the branches(`name`&`schemaExtensions`) explicitly. No need to write other key names such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "name": { "*": "&1" },
            "schemaExtensions": {
              "*": {
                "*": { "*": { "*": { "*": "&5.&1" } } }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: No because I'll lose array from rows. Also name should be element from bigger elment in row not a row itself. But your answer gave me good hint for another one I have to produce

Comment: I've answered depending on the current case, if you have other elements than `content` within the leaf elements, then just replace `"*": "&5.&1"` with `"content": "&5.&1"` @ChristianDemers